# Youtube 5 is always syncing on Android 2

Tags: sync, youtube

since I updated my YouTube app from the pre-installed version to 5.5.30 on my Android (version 2.3.5, kernel 2.6) which is running on a Samsung GT I9003, YouTube tries to sync something all the time.

I'm logged in with a YouTube account an can play all the videos without problems. 
But, YouTube uses most of the battery and the sync icon is always there.

Forcing the app to stop with the task manager sometimes fixes this issue.

Removing the update fixes the problem, but the default version is not really nice.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: yes, they are. I tried to disable and re-enable them, but nothing changes. Some research about similar problems with Google Wallet showed that they only solved it by downgrading to an older version.

Comment: Probably a typo, but there's no Android 2.6. Did you mean Android **2.3.6**?

Comment: thank you. I meant the kernel and forgot the android version.

Answer (score -1):

You can also download version 4 of youtube from 3rd party sites. It's more powerful than default version and does not have sync issue.